# how do I apply bootstrap styles only for django-crispy-forms not for other tags in the html template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

Upto know I used Bootstrap for the total project. But now I wanted to use my own styling for my Whole project. And I want to use crispy form tags for some forms like registration and login form.But when I tried it bootstrap styles are applying to my whole project.I don't want that I just want styling for only forms from ***crispy_forms***. How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
{% extends '../base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block extra_head %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
{% endblock extra_head %}
{% block content %}

<form method="post">
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">SignUp</button>  #styles applying for this button also
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be loading your crispy form tags before the form itself. I am sorry if this didn't work I am not that into bootstrap and i rarely use it.